Fractional Poincare inequality in one dimension
I am currently interested in proving the following inequality
$$\inf_{p\in\mathbb{R}}\|v-p\|_{W^{s,p}(0,1;L^2(\Omega))}\leq c[v]_{W^{s,p}(0,1;L^2(\Omega))}$$
where $v\in W^{s,p}(0,1;L^2(\Omega))$ and $ [u]_{ W^{s,p}(0,T;L^2(\Omega))}^p:=\int_{0}^T \int_{0}^T \frac{\|u(t)-u(\xi)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^p}{|t-\xi|^{1+s p}} d t d \xi$ is the semi-norm.
I found a paper talking about the fractional Poincare inequality https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3604 but in this paper, the inequality holds for dimension $n\geq 2$. I am wondering if this is also true for $n=1$. Are any references about this?
